# How to play a Minecraft Sound and keep it playing in the same location in Spigot 1.9

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I am having a bit of trouble with sounds in my bukkit plugin (Or Spigot 1.9) and the problem I have is I want to use this command:

`player.playSound(loc, Sound.RECORD_BLOCKS, 1f, 1f);`

Which works fine it's just. I want the sound to continue playing as the player runs around. So I find that when the command is executed, the sound plays and then as you move, the sound disappears and it can't be heard unless you go back to the place in which the command was executed.

Comment: Try `player.playSound(loc, "record.blocks", 1f, 1f);`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `player.playSound(Location location, Sound sound, float volume, float pitch)` method internally sends a packet to the client by specifying an effect and a given location. Therefore there is not way of changing the location without sending a new packet and duplicating the sound that the player is already hearing.

Nevertheless, the third parameter of the aforementioned method corresponds to the volume of the sound that is played. By increasing it, you can widen the radius within which the player can hear the sound. For instance, after a quick test, by setting it to 10, you can hear the music in an approximate 150 blocks radius.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks that worked great! I do remember now having to do that when using command blocks on the single player version of my map. So thanks :)

Comment: @Daniel: when you get a moment, would you accept this answer? To do so, click the tick mark to the left of it, so it turns green. This is how we thank people on the site. Thanks!